# JSON File multiple roots

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file I'm trying to manipulate in python but it seems the json formating is not correct:

{{"ticket":{"id":"123", "name":"bill"}},
{"ticket":{"id":"1234", "name":"james"}}}

When i try to format it using a json formatter it gives me Error multiple root elements

How can I fix it?

Update: with the suggestion from funqkey i updated the script:

```
import json
with open('ticketData8242020-6152021.json', 'r') as f:
     data = f.read()
     data = json.loads(data)
```

There is something wrong with the file. I will attempt to remove the ticket object references from the file. to fix it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Should look like this [{"ticket": {"id": "123", "name": "bill"}}, {"ticket": {"id": "1234", "name": "james"}}]

import json

with open('ticketData8242020-6152021.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

data = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: Sorry, I put up the wrong format, corrected now.

Comment: I did this by opening the file :import json

f = open("ticketData8242020-6152021.json")

data = json.loads(f) # but doesnt compile

Comment: I think this is correct but it is complaining about the last line of json file. ValueError: Expecting object: line 22483 column 7 (char 956534)

Comment: I dont think it likes the [] in the beginning and end.

Comment: The json is valid, if you try `json.loads('[{"ticket": {"id": "123", "name": "bill"}}, {"ticket": {"id": "1234", "name": "james"}}]')` it will work, my guess is that there is something wrong within your file.

Comment: Yes there is something wrong with the file. I will try to fix it thanks!

Comment: Im going to go through the file and remove the keys manually. Maybe that will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The problems here include

- `ticket` needs to be in quotes
- When you have multiple objects, you need a list, not a dict
- You can't have an object with multiple "ticket" keys.

I SUSPECT what you want is a list of objects, like this:

```
[{"id":"123", "name":"bill"}, {"id":"1234", "name":"james"}]
```

Or maybe a list of objects with one entry each, as funqkey suggested:

```
[{"ticket":{"id":"123", "name":"bill"}}, {"ticket":{"id":"1234", "name":"james"}}]
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, Ya i try to parse it with the sugestion of funqkey. but python complains about the format

Comment: Do you know an easy way to remove the ticket object keys? I was going to do it manually but its a 22000 line file.

Comment: Well, we don't know exactly what you have.  In the example you showed, if you change the outermost { } to [ ], then you could read it as JSON.  Once it's in Python, it's easy to pull the dict values and write it back as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, the keys should be quoted using `"`. Therefore

```
{{ticket:{"id":"123", "name":"bill"}}, {ticket:{"id":"1234", "name":"james"}}}
```

is not a valid JSON. **The corrected version** is

```
{{"ticket":{"id":"123", "name":"bill"}}, {"ticket":{"id":"1234", "name":"james"}}}
```

---

You can validate your JSON online: [JSON Online Validator and Formatter - JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com/)